# pand and zoom SVG image but when zoom in the image is not sharp

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg, svgpanzoom

I am developing an React Native project. Our backend returns a URL which points to a remote SVG image. I need to not only show the SVG but also be able to pan and zoom it in the mobile app.

- To show remote SVG image, I use [react-native-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg#use-with-content-loaded-from-uri) library.
- To pan and zoom SVG, I use [react-native-simple-svg-pan-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-svg-pan-zoom) library.

Here is what I tried:

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

// I hardcode the remote SVG URL here for illustration purpose, it is from backend in my code.
const imageSource = 'https://www.example.com/foo.svg';
...
return (
      <SvgPanZoom
          canvasHeight={windowHeight}
          canvasWidth={windowWidth}
          minScale={0.5}
          maxScale={10}
          initialZoom={1}
          onZoom={zoom => {
            console.log('onZoom:' + zoom);
          }}>
          <SvgUri width="100%" height="100%" uri={imageSource} />
        </SvgPanZoom>
  )
```

When run my app, the remote SVG image is shown & I can zoom in and out based on the configuration. But when zoom in, the SVG image is not sharp. It looks more like a bitmap being scaled. Here is an example how it looks like when I zoom in to the max scale (in above code snippet you can see `maxScale={10}`).

[image]

So, how can I zoom a remote SVG image ? If the libraries I am using is not a good choice, anyone can suggest me other libraries to solve my problem?

**==== Update 02.02.2021 ====**

I tried [react-native-image-zoom-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-zoom-viewer) as @Minh Vo suggested. However I get blank screen, the remote svg image is not rendered by the library.

```
const svgImage = [{url: data.image.url}];
return (
<ImageViewer
            enableImageZoom={true}
            ref={() => {}}
            onChange={() => {}}
            renderIndicator={() => null}
            backgroundColor={'transparent'}
              imageUrls={svgImage} />);
    ...
```

If you feel I should provide the URL of SVG for my question, you can use this as an example https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/Steps.svg

Comment: Probably because you have a width and a height  `canvasHeight={windowHeight}; canvasWidth={windowWidth}` Try declaring a viewBox attribute instead

Comment: do you mean remove the `canvasHeight` and `canvasWidth` and wrap the code inside `<View>...</View>` ? I don't see a component from the library named `viewBox`, could you please provide a code example?

Comment: Please read about the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute

Comment: Thanks. However in my case it is a remote SVG (from a remote uri), how can I modify its content to inject the `viewBox` in my react-native project? It would be nice if you could use some code snippet to illustrate.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029112/svg-viewbox-error-with-react

Comment: Are you sure that the remote SVG does not contain an image (bitmap)? Maybe it does.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes I am sure it doesn't contain bitmap.

Comment: we cant help you if you don't show us the remote svg as your problem isn't in the library or the solution but rather with this specific uri

Comment: @youssefali the remote SVG can be opened on any browser by its URL. It is a SVG. Nothing special. Unfortunately I can't provide the URL since it is not for public access at the moment. I don't see why providing the remote SVG url is so important for my question, it is just a normal SVG located on server & accessed by URL. For example I googled one remote SVG https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/Steps.svg , my SVG is nothing different than this one technically.

Comment: @Leem.fin do you find a way to zoom an SVG?

Comment: @Leem.fin what solution did you come up with? (if any)

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem and i find a library can help this. I suggest this [react-native-image-zoom-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-zoom-viewer). You can easy zoom in and zoom out even though url is 1 image or multi image. More infomation in that link. Here is code demo:

```
        const images = "www.abc.com/image.svg"
        <ImageViewer
            ref={() => {}}
            onChange={() => {}}
            renderIndicator={() => null}
            backgroundColor={'transparent'}
            index={this.state.index}
            imageUrls={this.images} />
```

Comment: Do you feel that library works well with SVG image? I mean when zoom in is the pixel still sharp?

Comment: I tried, the remote svg image is not shown at all.

Comment: sorry, i so busy, if this library not help for u, u can try with this library: [react-native-svg-uri](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri)
`import SvgUri from "react-native-svg-uri";`
`<SvgUri
              width={}
              source={{
                uri: image_url
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
            />`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you provide for `react-native-simple-svg-pan-zoom`,

> It is recommended not to set maxScale above 1 as this results in blurred react-native-svg elements. Instead, increase your SVG element dimensions and set minScale lower.

So I guess you should choose a `maxScale` below 1 and try lower values for `minScale` coupled with higher values for `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` until you get the zoom levels you need.